# Is it possible to connect single Heroku-RedisToGo from 2 different Heroku instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku, redis

I have one Rails instance and another Node.js instance. The plan is to publish information from the Rails project using Redis's pubsub and subscribe by the Node.js program. The node.js program will publish the information to other clients through web sockets (or long polls).

The whole thing is working perfectly while deployed in combination of remote linux machines. On Heroku, Redis To Go is added as an add-on with the Rails instance. Redis can be connected and working fine from this instance.

But I am not getting how to reach to this Redis add-on from the Node.js instance. I've added `REDISTOGO_URL` from the environment of Rails instance to the environment of Node.js, but it's not working. Sample errors I'm getting (from logs and REPL) are

```
redis.set("a","b");  
  ==> Error: Connection in pub/sub mode, only pub/sub commands may be used
redis.psubscribe('*');  
  ==> false
```

Can somebody please show me a way how to accomplish this?

Comment: If you've set the REDISTOGO_URL config correctly for the second app it will connect just the same - I think the problem here lies in your node code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all you have to do is set the heroku config value similar to:

'heroku config:add REDISTOGO_URL=[your redis togo url]'

Heroku will then add your config var and restart your app.

You can check to make sure it's added correctly by doing a 'heroku config' on both repositories and comparing them.